# Terminal command to clear DNS cache doesn't seem to work

Tags: macos, terminal, safari, dns

I do a lot of website work where I change nameservers for a domain, wait overnight for it to propagate on the host server, then go back to work on the site. Lately, what happens is that I can see the new site at the new location on my iPhone but not on my Mac (OS X 10.11.5), using any browser (Safari, FF, Chrome). 
This suggests I need to clear my DNS cache. I've tried two different Terminal commands for 10.11+:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder #(from Apple Support)
```

or

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Then I restart OS X, empty browser caches, clear cookies. Nothing helps to get me to the new location, in any browser. But I can see it from my iPhone! This is maddening. Anybody know what I can do to get my Mac to recognize the new IP address for that nameserver?

Comment: Can you issue the command:  `system_profiler SPNetworkDataType | grep -i dns -A7` and paste the results.  You can append `| pbcopy` to the end of the statement to send it to your clipboard

Comment: DNS:
          Domain Name: PK5001Z
          Server Addresses: 192.168.0.1, 205.171.2.26
      DHCP Server Responses:
          Domain Name: PK5001Z
          Domain Name Servers: 192.168.0.1,205.171.2.26
          Lease Duration (seconds): 0
          DHCP Message Type: 0x05

Comment: I forgot to ask... is your iPhone connected to WiFi or are you going off your cell data network?  Your DNS appears to have you router as it's primary DNS. I will bet it's caching DNS records and hasn't updated.  Try resetting your router.

Comment: My iPhone is connected to WiFi and the same router, but I like your suggestion and will try that.  Is there a configuration that would prevent this from happening? Thanks so much!